# Using an Image from an array in a toast in android

Tags: android, arrays, image, toast

I am making an android app that lets the user play the drinking game kings. I have all the @drawable images in an array 'cards' which are randomly selected. I can't figure out how to display the images in a toast **without** creating a layout or setting the toast to just one image.

Here's what i got so far...

The array:

```
final int [] cards = {R.drawable.twoofdiamonds, R.drawable.threeofdiamonds, R.drawable.fourofdiamonds, R.drawable.fiveofdiamonds, R.drawable.sixofdiamonds,
          R.drawable.sevenofdiamonds, R.drawable.eightofdiamonds, R.drawable.nineofdiamonds, R.drawable.tenofdiamonds, R.drawable.jofdiamonds, R.drawable.qofdiamonds,
          R.drawable.kofdiamonds, R.drawable.aceofdiamonds, R.drawable.twoofclubs, R.drawable.threeofclubs, R.drawable.fourofclubs, R.drawable.fiveofclubs,
          R.drawable.sixofclubs, R.drawable.sevenofclubs, R.drawable.eightofclubs, R.drawable.nineofclubs, R.drawable.tenofclubs, R.drawable.jofclubs,
          R.drawable.qofclubs, R.drawable.kofclubs, R.drawable.aceofclubs, R.drawable.twoofhearts, R.drawable.threeofhearts, R.drawable.fourofhearts,
          R.drawable.fiveofhearts, R.drawable.sixofhearts, R.drawable.sevenofhearts, R.drawable.eightofhearts, R.drawable.nineofhearts, R.drawable.tenofhearts, R.drawable.jofhearts,
          R.drawable.qofhearts, R.drawable.kofhearts, R.drawable.aceofhearts, R.drawable.twoofspades, R.drawable.threeofspades, R.drawable.fourofspades,
          R.drawable.fiveofspades, R.drawable.sixofspades, R.drawable.sevenofspades, R.drawable.eightofspades, R.drawable.ninefspades, R.drawable.tenofspades,
          R.drawable.jofspades, R.drawable.qofspades, R.drawable.kofspades, R.drawable.aceofspades};
```

The attempt I made at the Image toast:

```
Toast ImageToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
        LinearLayout toastLayout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
        toastLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
        TextView text = new TextView(getBaseContext());

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cards[randomSequence[cardCount]]); //error here

        text.setText("Hello!");
        toastLayout.addView(image);
        toastLayout.addView(text);
        ImageToast.setView(toastLayout);
        ImageToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        ImageToast.show();
```

Any help welcome, I'm a noob at this. Cheers.

Comment: what error are you getting there? What is this randomSequence[cardCount]

Comment: http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/custom-notification-in-android-with-an-example/

Comment: @Naveen Cannot resolve symbol 'cards', the randomSequence is shuffling the images in the array and the cardCount is just a int that increases each time the shuffle has been run.

Comment: you can't call cards array like that. You need to use just cards[int] instead of R.drawable.cards[int].

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Toast class which extends Toast.

```
public class CustomToast extends Toast {
    public CustomToast(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomToast(Context context, int resourceId) {
            super(context);
            ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
            img.setImageResource(resourceId);
            setView(img);
    }
}
```

You can call it using

```
new CustomToast(getApplicationContext(), cards[randomSequence[cardCount]]).show();
```